# Error redirection in the body of the bash shell function

Tags: bash, shell, stdout, io-redirection, stderr

I have a script like the one below:

```
#!/bin/bash
#func.sh 
func(){
badcommand1
echo "OK"
badcomand2
 }
func  2>&1  > err.log
#The top line is in the file
```

My goal is to redirect all outputs and errors to file err.log but unfortunately, it only prints
"OK" to the log file.

Bash version is:
GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Can anybody help?

Comment: Note that the question title is a misnomer — you are doing the redirection outside the function, not inside it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest to swap `2>&1` and `> err.log`.

From `man bash`:

```
Note that the order of redirections is significant. For example,
the command

ls > dirlist 2>&1

directs both standard output and standard error to the file
dirlist, while the command

ls 2>&1 > dirlist

directs only the standard output to file dirlist, because the
standard error was duplicated from the standard output before
the standard output was redirected to dirlist.
```